# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sv'

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
    package org.citi.sentimentapi;

    @RestController
    public class SentimentController{

        @Autowired
        private SentimentService sv;

        @RequestMapping("/sentiment/{text}")
        public double apply(@PathVariable String text) throws Exception  {
            return sv.apply(text);
        }   
}
```

The below exception is coming:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sentimentController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sv'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sentimentService' defined in file [C:\Users\MG23625\Desktop\workspace\sentiment-apiImproved\target\classes\org\citi\sentimentapi\SentimentService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.citi.sentimentapi.SentimentService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: in must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.citi.sentimentapi.Sentiment.main(Sentiment.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sentimentService' defined in file [C:\Users\MG23625\Desktop\workspace\sentiment-apiImproved\target\classes\org\citi\sentimentapi\SentimentService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.citi.sentimentapi.SentimentService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: in must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.citi.sentimentapi.SentimentService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: in must not be null
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in must not be null
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:194) ~[opennlp-tools-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:173) ~[opennlp-tools-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel.<init>(POSModel.java:82) ~[opennlp-tools-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.citi.sentimentapi.SentimentService$POSTagger.<init>(SentimentService.java:120) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.citi.sentimentapi.SentimentService$SentimentAnalyzer.<init>(SentimentService.java:289) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.citi.sentimentapi.SentimentService.<init>(SentimentService.java:388) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

My code:

```
 package org.citi.sentimentapi;

  @Service
    public class SentimentService {

        class Word
        {
            public Word(String word, String pennTag)
            {
                if (word == null || word.isEmpty())
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("word");
                if (pennTag == null || pennTag.isEmpty())
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("posTagInfo");

                this.word = word.toLowerCase();
                this.pennTag = pennTag.toUpperCase();

                tag = fromPennTreebankTag(pennTag);
            }
            private String word;
            public String getWord() {return word;}
            private String pennTag;
            public String getPennTag() {return pennTag;}
            private String tag;
            public String getTag() {return tag;}
            public boolean hasTag() {return tag != null;}

            String fromPennTreebankTag(String value)
            {
                return
                    value.startsWith("J") ? "a" :
                    value.startsWith("V") ? "v" :
                    value.startsWith("N") ? "n" :
                    value.startsWith("R") ? "r" : null;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return hasTag() ? word + ":" + tag : word;
            }
        }

        abstract class Phrase
        {
            public Phrase(Word[] words)
            {
                if (words.length == 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                this.words = words;
            }
            private Word[] words;
            public Word[] getWords() {return words;}
            public abstract double modifyScore(double value);
        }

        class Incrementer extends Phrase
        {
            public Incrementer(Word... words) {super(words);}
            @Override
            public double modifyScore(double value) {return value * 2;}
        }

        class Inverter extends Phrase
        {
            public Inverter(Word... words) {super(words);}
            @Override
            public double modifyScore(double value) {return value * -1;}
        }

        class Decrementer extends Phrase
        {
            public Decrementer(Word... words) {super(words);}
            @Override
            public double modifyScore(double value) {return value / 2;}
        }

        class POSTagger
        {
            POSTaggerME posTagger;
            Tokenizer tokenizer;
            SentenceDetectorME sentDetector;

            public POSTagger() throws IOException
            {
                ClassLoader loader = getClass().getClassLoader();
                //ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

                posTagger = new POSTaggerME(
                        new POSModel(loader.getResourceAsStream("en-pos-maxent.bin")));
                tokenizer = new TokenizerME(
                        new TokenizerModel(loader.getResourceAsStream("en-token.bin")));
                sentDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(
                        new SentenceModel(loader.getResourceAsStream("en-sent.bin")));
            }

            public Word[][] tag(String input)
            {
                String[] sents = sentDetector.sentDetect(input);
                Word[][] res = new Word[sents.length][];

                for (int i = 0; i < sents.length; i++)
                {
                    String[] words = tokenizer.tokenize(sents[i]);
                    String[] tags = posTagger.tag(words);
                    Word[] sentence = new Word[words.length];

                    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++)
                        sentence[j] = new Word(words[j], tags[j]);

                    res[i] = sentence;
                }
                return res;
            }
        }

        class WordNetLemmatizer
        {
            Dictionary dictionary;
            public WordNetLemmatizer() throws JWNLException
            {
                //dictionary = Dictionary.getDefaultResourceInstance();
            }

            public Word getLemmatized(Word word) throws JWNLException
            {
                if (!word.hasTag())
                    return word;

                IndexWord iw = dictionary.lookupIndexWord(POS.getPOSForKey(word.getTag()), word.getWord());
                if (iw == null)
                    return word;

                String lemma = iw.getLemma();
                if (lemma == null || lemma.isEmpty())
                    return word;

                return new Word(lemma, word.getPennTag());
            }
        }

        abstract class SentimentDictionary
        {
            abstract double getScore(Word word);
        }

        class SentiWordNet extends SentimentDictionary
        {
            String path = "C:\\Users\\MG23625\\Downloads\\SentiWordNet_3.0.0\\home\\swn\\www\\admin\\dump\\SentiWordNet_3.0.0_20130122.txt";
            Map<String, Double> dictionary;

            public SentiWordNet() throws IOException
            {
                // This is our main dictionary representation
                dictionary = new HashMap<>();

                // From String to list of doubles.
                HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, Double>> tempDictionary = new HashMap<>();

                try (BufferedReader csv = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)))
                {
                    int lineNumber = 0;

                    String line;
                    while ((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        lineNumber++;

                        // If it's a comment, skip this line.
                        if (!line.trim().startsWith("#"))
                        {
                            // We use tab separation
                            String[] data = line.split("\t");
                            String wordTypeMarker = data[0];

                            // Example line:
                            // POS ID PosS NegS SynsetTerm#sensenumber Desc
                            // a 00009618 0.5 0.25 spartan#4 austere#3 ascetical#2
                            // ascetic#2 practicing great self-denial;...etc

                            // Is it a valid line? Otherwise, through exception.
                            if (data.length != 6)
                            {
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                                        "Incorrect tabulation format in file, line: " + lineNumber);
                            }

                            // Calculate synset score as score = PosS - NegS
                            Double synsetScore =
                                    Double.parseDouble(data[2]) - Double.parseDouble(data[3]);

                            // Get all Synset terms
                            String[] synTermsSplit = data[4].split(" ");

                            // Go through all terms of current synset.
                            for (String synTermSplit : synTermsSplit)
                            {
                                // Get synterm and synterm rank
                                String[] synTermAndRank = synTermSplit.split("#");
                                String synTerm = synTermAndRank[0] + "#" + wordTypeMarker;

                                int synTermRank = Integer.parseInt(synTermAndRank[1]);
                                // What we get here is a map of the type:
                                // term -> {score of synset#1, score of synset#2...}

                                // Add map to term if it doesn't have one
                                if (!tempDictionary.containsKey(synTerm))
                                    tempDictionary.put(synTerm, new HashMap<Integer, Double>());

                                // Add synset link to synterm
                                tempDictionary.get(synTerm).put(synTermRank, synsetScore);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Go through all the terms.
                    for (Map.Entry<String, HashMap<Integer, Double>> entry : tempDictionary.entrySet())
                    {
                        String word = entry.getKey();
                        Map<Integer, Double> synSetScoreMap = entry.getValue();

                        // Calculate weighted average. Weigh the synsets according to
                        // their rank.
                        // Score= 1/2*first + 1/3*second + 1/4*third ..... etc.
                        // Sum = 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 ...
                        double score = 0.0;
                        double sum = 0.0;
                        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> setScore : synSetScoreMap.entrySet())
                        {
                            score += setScore.getValue() / (double) setScore.getKey();
                            sum += 1.0 / (double) setScore.getKey();
                        }
                        score /= sum;

                        dictionary.put(word, score);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public double getScore(Word word)
            {
                if (!word.hasTag())
                    return Double.NaN;
                return dictionary.getOrDefault(word.getWord() + "#" + word.getTag(), Double.NaN);
            }
        }

        class SentimentAnalyzer
        {
            Map<String, Phrase> phrases;
            POSTagger posTagger;
            WordNetLemmatizer lemmatizer;
            SentimentDictionary sentimentDict;

            public SentimentAnalyzer(SentimentDictionary dictionary) throws JWNLException, IOException
            {
                lemmatizer = new WordNetLemmatizer();
                posTagger = new POSTagger();
                sentimentDict = dictionary;

                phrases = new HashMap<>();

                addPhrase(new Inverter(new Word("lack", "NN"), new Word("of", "IN")));
                addPhrase(new Inverter(new Word("not", "RB")));
                addPhrase(new Inverter(new Word("n't", "RB")));

                addPhrase(new Incrementer(new Word("too", "RB")));
                addPhrase(new Incrementer(new Word("very", "RB")));
                addPhrase(new Incrementer(new Word("sorely", "RB")));

                addPhrase(new Decrementer(new Word("barely", "RB")));
                addPhrase(new Decrementer(new Word("little", "RB")));
            }

            void addPhrase(Phrase value) throws JWNLException
            {
                phrases.put(value.getWords()[0].getWord(), value);
            }

            public double getScore(String input) throws JWNLException
            {
                double totalScore = 0;
                Word[][] sentences = posTagger.tag(input);
                for (Word[] sentence : sentences)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++)
                    {
                        Word word = sentence[i];
                        Phrase p = phrases.get(word.getWord());
                        Phrase phrase = null;

                        if (p != null &&
                            sentence.length - i > p.getWords().length &&
                            containsPhrase(sentence, i, p.getWords()))
                        {
                            phrase = p;
                            i += phrase.getWords().length;
                            int j = i;
                            for (; j < sentence.length && !sentence[j].hasTag(); j++) ;
                            if (j == sentence.length)
                                continue;
                            word = sentence[j];
                        }
                        else if (!word.hasTag())
                            continue;

                        double score = sentimentDict.getScore(word);
                        if (Double.isNaN(score))
                        {
                            word = lemmatizer.getLemmatized(word);
                            score = sentimentDict.getScore(word);
                        }

                        if (!Double.isNaN(score))
                        {
                            if (phrase != null)
                            {
                                score = phrase.modifyScore(score);

                                //out.format("<%s> ", String.join(" ",
                                //  stream(phrase.getWords()).map(Word::toString).toArray(String[]::new)));
                            }
                            //out.format("%s:%.2f ", word, score);

                            totalScore += score;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //out.format("%s ", word);
                        }
                    }
                    //out.println();
                }
                return totalScore;
            }

            boolean containsPhrase(Word[] sentence, int index, Word[] phrase)
            {
                if (phrase.length == 0 ||
                    index >= sentence.length ||
                    sentence.length - index < phrase.length)
                {return false;}

                for (int pi = 0, si = index; pi < phrase.length; pi++, si++)
                {
                    if (sentence[si].getWord().compareTo(phrase[pi].getWord()) != 0 ||
                        sentence[si].getPennTag().compareTo(phrase[pi].getPennTag()) != 0)
                    {return false;}
                }
                return true;
            }
        }

        public SentimentService() throws Exception
        {
            if (analyzer == null)
                analyzer = new SentimentAnalyzer(new SentiWordNet());   
            //setCacheable(true);
        }

        static SentimentAnalyzer analyzer;

         public double apply(String input) throws Exception
            {
                double score = analyzer.getScore(input);            
                return score;
            }


    }
```

I commented setCacheable(true) as it was giving an error. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You got NPE in constructor of `POSTagger` at line 120.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in must not be null
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:194) ~[opennlp-tools-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:173) ~[opennlp-tools-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel.<init>(POSModel.java:82) ~[opennlp-tools-1.7.2.jar:1.7.2]
    at org.citi.sentimentapi.SentimentService$POSTagger.<init>(SentimentService.java:120) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.citi.sentimentapi.SentimentService$SentimentAnalyzer.<init>(SentimentService.java:289) ~[classes/:na]
```

On how to do it check [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

But honestly, you better refactor your code, or you will have plenty of such "untracable" exceptions ins the future as it is super messy.

Start by moving classes to separate `java` files.